# Click report by Click activity (SMC)

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, tracking

everyone! I have another question and hope for your assistance.

Intro: Our SMC platform has a "Tracking" section where we can view analytics for campaign sends. In this analytics, we can download a table showing the counts of unique clicks on the email (in Overview). We find the analytics we need in the "Click Activity" section, but I am unsure how to download it along with the required data.

Question: Are there any methods(SQL queries) to create a Data Extension (DE) that contains all the data from "Click Activity" related to clicks, including the ***Subscriber key, email, click time,id, link, total and unique clicks*** in the table?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is most probably [_Click Data View](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5). It holds all clicks made by your subscribers across all emails. You can join this with the [_Job Data View](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_job.htm&language=en_US&type=5), to identify jobs which sent specific emails, if you want to limit the clicks to only those coming from some of your emails.

The last use case can be achieved with a query similar to this:

```sql
SELECT
c.*
FROM _Click c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    JobID
    ,EmailName
    FROM _Job 
) j ON j.JobID = c.JobID
WHERE j.EmailName = 'Email Name'
```

Remember, _Job Data View is the only data view that is specific to a particular Business Unit.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Am I right, that that query will show all clicks for each link in the result?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct @LarisaRusinovich

Comment: And if I need only 1 JobID, will be this code correct?
SELECT
    c.*
FROM _Click c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        JobID
        ,EmailName
    FROM _Job 
    WHERE JobID = 63
) j ON j.JobID = c.JobID
WHERE j.EmailName = 'Email Name'

Comment: @LarisaRusinovich - You don't need to join Job table for this, only:  _SELECT * FROM _Click where JobID = 63_

Comment: @LarisaRusinovich - remember to mark my answer as accepted, if it has been helpful